# Jest error MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection

Tags: node.js, jestjs, supertest

I'm trying to learn testing with jest and supertest. I have this simple API:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ name: "bob" });
});
app.delete("/delete", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Todos.deleteOne({ _id: req.body.id });
  res.send(result);
});
app.post("/add", (req, res) => {
  const { item, status } = req.body;
  const todo = new Todos({
    item,
  });
  todo.save();
  res.send(todo);
});
```

They all work. I also have these tests **which when individually run they all pass, but when I run them together the `delete` fails.

My logic is, when adding a post, I'm passing the id of the created post to the test so that the `delete` test can use

```
const request = require("supertest"); 
const app = require("../server");
describe("testing Todos API", () => {
  let payload = { id: "6156c95c9ecf28237844489b" };
  let item = { item: "test" };
  it("get", (done) => {
    request(app)
      .get("/")
      .expect(200)
      .end((err, res) => {
        expect(res.body).toEqual({ name: "bob" });
        expect(res.body.name).toEqual("bob");
        done();
      });
  });
  it("post", (done) => {
    request(app)
      .post("/add")
      .send(item)
      .expect(200)
      .end((err, res) => {
        payload.id = res.body._id;
        expect(res.body.item).toEqual(item.item);
        done();
      });
  });
  it("delete", (done) => {
    request(app)
      .delete("/delete")
      .send(payload)
      .end((err, res) => {
        console.log(res.body);
        expect(res.body.deletedCount).toEqual(1);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

But I get the error of `error MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection` and `deletedCount` is `0`